# UIDatePicker produces feedback after scrolling is finished. Explanation required

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8, uidatepicker

So I have UIDatePicker initialized programmatically. It has some subviews with `NSLayoutConstraints`. Also it has a custom text color `setValue(textColor, forKey:"textColor")`. It is positioned in superview with the help of `NSLayoutConstraints`.

Every time it stops scrolling some text is produced in Debug area:

**<_UIFeedbackRetargetBehavior: 0x60000011b750: prepared=0> is being deactivated more times that it'd been activated, this will raise soon!**

So I'm a bit worried. Google finds nothing... Does anybody have an explanation?

*Xcode 8. Swift 3. iPhone SE simulator.*

Comment: if you use a plain UIDatePicker without custom text color or layout constraints, do you still get the same errors appearing in the console?

Comment: I'll check tomorrow

Comment: I don't see the feedback anymore (changed nothing). Maybe mac reboot fixed the issue...

Comment: I just had the exact same issue (Xcode 8.1, Swift 3, iPhone 6 Plus). The debug message makes no sense at all. What is being deactivated, and what will raise soon, and what does "raise" mean? I think this might be something goofy with Xcode 8.x.

Comment: I just had the exact same issue (Xcode 8.1, Swift 3, iPhone 5). I did nothing but recompile and the message is gone.

Comment: "raise" means raise an error/exception, I would guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you still encounter this issue.

What helped for me was making the UIPickerView a class member (not a variable in method's context).

Or you could also have it created in the storyboard/.xib file and link it as an IBOutlet to your class.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem I solved it leaving the first space of the array
Example

```
_Distance = @[@"", @"1Km",@"2Km",@"3Km"];
```